# Conditional sed with a grep

Tags: bash, sed, grep, jq

I want to use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) to conditionally change the **team** name to **fruit** if the **food** on the line below contains the word
`raspberry`
`strawberry`
`apple`
but to leave it alone if the search isn't matched. An example of the file contents below:

```
{
"team":"veg",
"food":"raspberry",
},
{
"team":"veg",
"food":"carrot",
},
{
"team":"veg",
"food":"strawberry",
}
```

Happy to use another tool if it's better suited :) I will be replacing the file (ideally), so will probably need sed with the -i flag.

Thanks

Comment: `jq` would be the recommended means of doing this...

Comment: Or just any json parser

Comment: I'm using jq to parse the text (jq '.'), will it work with conditional statements?

Comment: At the moment, your example isn't valid JSON...is this really the case?

Comment: @user3229731, tell me what is your `jq` version?

Comment: No, this is a small piece of text, the actual json is 2mb. I'm running jq version 1.5.

Comment: Did you notice the comment about your example is *not* valid JSON?

Comment: I'll change it now so it's the head and tail of the file.

Comment: Don't make your example unnecessarily complex, just tidy up what you've got to make it valid.

Answer (score 4):

Here we are, ***jq*** approach:

A valid json input should look like (let's say `test.json`):

```
[
  {
    "team": "veg",
    "food": "raspberry"
  },
  {
    "team": "veg",
    "food": "carrot"
  },
  {
    "team": "veg",
    "food": "strawberry"
  }
]
```

---

```
jq 'map(select(.food == "strawberry" or .food == "raspberry" or .food == "apple").team |="fruit")' test.json
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "team": "fruit",
    "food": "raspberry"
  },
  {
    "team": "veg",
    "food": "carrot"
  },
  {
    "team": "fruit",
    "food": "strawberry"
  }
]
```

> `map(x)` For any filter *x*, *map(x)* will run that filter for each
>   element of the input array, and return the outputs in a new array

`|="fruit"` - *update assignment*, https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Assignment

Comment: This looks promising, I'll test it now!

Comment: Perfect, works really well - I wish I'd have thought of doing this sooner, jq really came to the rescue!

Comment: @user3229731, yes, I also like this tool